# Perl : How to print to console while writing to file

Tags: perl

Apologies for what I'm sure is a very simple question, but here goes.

How can I print a message to the console if I have a command line parameter to write to file? Here's what I have on the command line:

```
script.pl > outputFile.txt
```

And then, in the script

```
do_something(); # Prints output to file
print ("Done something."); # How can I make this print to the console?
```

I have a feeling I should be using a different method of printing the output of `do_something();` to the file, but if possible I'd like to leave the file specified as a parameter on the command line.

Comment: Have you misunderstood something? The `>` redirects standard output from script.pl to outputFile.txt. It is not a parameter passed on to Perl, but only used by your shell.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Print to STDERR

```
print STDERR "message\n";
```

Comment: "`print STDERR`" can be written more concisely as "`warn`". But this doesn't really gtet round the problem as STDERR can also be redirected to a file.